# Chromecast webkitvisibilitychange events not firing on TV when changing to different source

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I'm trying to implement the visibility state change event listeners for the chromecast receiver application so that upon changing to a different input on the TV I can pause playback of the content. This appears to be possible and is requested of receiver applications at the [receiver developer guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver).

I checked out [google chrome's page visibility information](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility) and followed that to make sure I was adding it correctly. My code looks like:

```
var handleVisibilityChange = function() {
  console.log('visibility changed');
  console.log(document.webkitHidden);
  console.log(document.webkitVisibilityState);
};
document.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

When I run the receiver app on my computer in chrome the event is fired every time I select or de-select the tab. However it has yet to fire when I'm changing to different input sources on the chromecast or get called if I pull the chromecast out of the HDMI port it was in without severing the power connection. I've also tried on several televisions including a Samsung TV & Sony GTV.

Comment: Maybe the event is triggered at the sender application?

Comment: The sender application isn't a web app so I doubt that would be the case. Are you suggesting that the event is sent back to the native application via the chromecast API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether that event is fired or not depends on the HDMI stack implemented in your TV, so there is no guaranty that it will be fired on your TV.

On a related note, a recent Chromecast update has broken that feature which will be fixed in future updates, so you will not be able to see that right now even if the HDMI-CEC stack was providing that functionality.

Comment: Any idea when this would be live and when it does get fixed if it will support more TV's?

Comment: Don't have any timeline to share yet. As for supporting more TVs, that is not up to the chromecast device; it is mainly a function of the TV's HDMI stack to notify the Chromecast device so there won't be any change in support when the issue is fixed.